# MSDTC attempts to enlist client machine in a distributed transaction

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, msdtc, distributed-transactions, system.transactions

We're seeing the following intermittent warning logged by MSDTC:

> A caller has attempted to propagate a
>   transaction to a remote system, but
>   MSDTC network DTC access is currently
>   disabled on machine 'X'. Please review
>   the MS DTC configuration settings.

However, MSDTC is disabled on machine X by design - it's a client machine, and has no business being enlisted in the transaction!

- Several windows service endpoints hosting WCF services over TCP
- Single SQL Server 2005 instance beneath
- Linq to Sql
- Remote client receives event callbacks over WCF/TCP

The issue is tricky to reproduce - usually following restart of services.  We suspect a callback to the client machine is occurring within the context of a transaction.

Just wondering if anyone has seen similar issues??

Ken